# Why the background is not centered here?

Tags: html, css

I want this site is correctly visualized on mobile devices.

This is the site: [Test](http://aszx.altervista.org/test/TanaTest/)

This is how it appears on mobile devices: [Mobile image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08izS.png)

This is my code:

css:

```
  #storia{
   padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
   text-align:center;  
   line-height: 1.2em;
   background:url(img/homeback2.png) no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   height:700px;
  }

  #storiatesto1{
   margin:0 auto;
   margin-top: 15px;
   width: 530px;
   font-family: 'Courgette', serif;
   font-size:14px;
  }

   #storiatesto2{
   margin:0 auto;
   width:450px;
   font-family: 'Courgette', serif;
   font-size:14px;
  }

#doc { margin: 10px 0; }
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 75px; border: solid 1px #CCC; padding:7px; background:white;
    width:530px;
}

.blueberry { max-width: 960px; }
.blueberry img { width:100%; }
```

html:

```
<body>

<div id="storia">

<div id="doc">
  <div id="content">

<!-- blueberry -->

<div class="blueberry">
  <img src="home.jpg" />
</div>

<!-- blueberry -->

  </div>
</div>

<div id="storiatesto1">
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ...
</div>


<div id="storiatesto2">
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ...
</div>



</div>

    </body>
```

Comment: done but it does not work :(

Comment: see here: http://jsfiddle.net/he9feghx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have fixed the width and the background image is centered according to that width. Try

```css
    #storiatesto1{
       margin:0 auto;
       margin-top: 15px;
       width: 80%;
       font-family: 'Courgette', serif;
       font-size:14px;
      }
    #storiatesto2{
       margin:0 auto;
       width:80%;
       font-family: 'Courgette', serif;
       font-size:14px;
      }
```

Also give the container with background a background size, for example

```css
      #storia{
       padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
       text-align:center;  
       line-height: 1.2em;
       background:url(img/homeback2.png) no-repeat;
       background-position: center center;
       height:700px;
       background-size:100% auto
      }
```

Comment: I've reduced the width to 50%; to fit the background image appropriately. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejd6cdrs/3) and [Results](http://jsfiddle.net/ejd6cdrs/3/embedded/result)

Comment: it's the best solution so far, but the background is a little distorted.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, image is going to be stretched, images are not responsive. That's why they are barely used in background like that except for patterns. You can also try SVG but it can time consuming. Also, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as correct :) Thank you.